# Suggestions. animation when scrolls down

Tags: javascript, scroll, triggers

what idea how such a website is created?
https://www.protohomes.com

I am not concerned with the appearance, but with the scrolling.
that is, an animation when it scrolls down the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [WhatRuns](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatruns/cmkdbmfndkfgebldhnkbfhlneefdaaip). It is a chrome extension to see what technologies are used on the site.
In the specific, the website uses those: https://www.whatruns.com/website/protohomes.com

Comment: Carmine 
I didn't think about checking it :)
thank you